# Access existing Correlation ID

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, trace

When returning `Problem` result ASP.NET generates standartized responce model that includes `"traceId": "00-d98512464f3f5a4b9ac3b8e02a03ecd0-8720663d0b55c94a-00"`. That `traceId` is actually Correlation id since it includes Span Id and other stuff.

That's great for error responses, but I also want to get that value for valid ones. Possible solution for this is to add it to response headers.

Issue is I have no idea, how to get it (except calling `Problem().Value` and getting it from there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.activity?view=net-5.0))

It has the properties `SpanId`, `TraceId` and `Id`. `Id` returns the same value as `Problem` result (*00-d98512464f3f5a4b9ac3b8e02a03ecd0-8720663d0b55c94a-00* in your case).